# How to pass percentage value to width to React data grid column

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-data-grid

Below is my Reactdata grid code

```
    this._columns = [
          {
            key: 'id',
            name: 'ID',
            width: 40
          },
          {
            key: 'task',
            name: 'Title',
            width:100
          },
          {
            key: 'priority',
            name: 'Priority',
            width:100
          },
          {
            key: 'issueType',
            name: 'Issue Type',
            width:100
          },
          {
            key: 'complete',
            name: '% Complete',
            width:100
          },
          {
            key: 'startDate',
            name: 'Start Date',
            width:100
          },
          {
            key: 'completeDate',
            name: 'Expected Complete',
            width:100
          }
        ];

          render() {
        return  (
          <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this._columns}
            rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
            rowsCount={this._rows.length}
            minHeight={500}
            minColumnWidth={120} 
          />);
      }
```

Using below React data grid:
https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid

I want to pass width as a percentage, how we can achieve with React data grid.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: minColumnWidth=“120%” or minColumnWidth={‘120%’}

Comment: If you don’t specify anything then react by default add px to the number value

Comment: @Think-Twice tried with minColumnWidth but not working

Answer (score 2):

I know maybe it is late but you can achieve this by setting the value as string

```js
const columns = [
  {
    key: 'Month',
    name: 'Mes',
    width: '50%',
  },
  {
    key: 'Tickets',
    name: 'Tickets',
    width: '10%',
  },
 ];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I thought this was really useful till I realized this works on the headers but not the rows. Is there another setting for rows or do you need to do a custom render?

Answer (score 1):

To make a given column resizable, set `column.resizable = true`.

If you need to know when a `column` has been resized, use the `onColumnResize` prop. This will be triggered when a column is resized and will report the column index and its new width. 
These can be saved on the back-end and used to restore column widths when the component is initialized, by setting `width` key in each column.

pass `resizable:true` which you want to resize like below.

```
this._columns = [
  {
    key: 'id',
    name: 'ID',
    resizable: true,
    width: 40
  },
  {
    key: 'task',
    name: 'Title',
    resizable: true
  }]
```

[refer here for more info](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/resizable-cols)

Comment: I don't want resizable, fix width as per screen size

Comment: then you may have to pass `locked: true` with coloumns

Comment: @Isa4299
no not working
need to pass column width is the percentage and it should adjust as per screen size

Comment: As of MUI V5, `resizable` is probably unavailable for MIT (free) version. When I use it, I saw the following message on the console: `Failed prop type: MUI: `column.resizable = true` is not a valid prop.
Column resizing is not available in the MIT version.`

Answer (score 0):

To pass with as percentage in a react component you just need to do the following width='100%'.

Comment: I want it with React data grid
I tried passing width='50%' but not working

Comment: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1339#issuecomment-488678166